# How to do sharing on instagram from PWA or web?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have an IOS and through ios we can use their SDK to share on Instagram. but i did not find any solution to share on Instagram from web or PWA.
Please let me know how i can share posts on instagram from web?

Comment: Also waiting for an answer. Similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65575462/sharing-on-instagram-on-pc-web